# how to get the unique result using django queryset?

Tags: django, django-queryset

```
class DateRange(models.Model):
   id = models....
   date = models....
```

```
01-01-2021 1
02-01-2021 1
03-01-2021 1
04-01-2021 1
05-01-2021 1
06-01-2021 1
07-01-2021 1
08-01-2021 1
09-01-2021 1

01-02-2021 2
02-02-2021 2
03-02-2021 2
04-02-2021 2
05-02-2021 2
06-02-2021 2
07-01-2021 2

01-03-2021 1
02-03-2021 1
```

I have something like this data in my DB. I want to get the result like

1 is present from 01-01-2021 - 09-01-2021
2 is present from 01-02-2021 - 07-01-2021
1 is present from 01-03-2021 - 02-03-2021

How to achieve this using the django queryset.

Comment: Have a look at [Django Docs - Making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#making-queries)

Comment: Can you show expected results please?